# Show image while loading data into gridView - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, gridview, datagridview, picturebox

I have tried to create a custom **picturebox** which I want to show only when data is loading into **datagridview**, but not successfully.

What I'm doing wrong. This is an example of my code.

```
      'creating picturebox

    pic.CreateControl()
    pic.Visible = True
    pic.Width = 222
    pic.Height = 173
    Dim x As Integer = 602
    Dim y As Integer = 207
    pic.ImageLocation = ("C:\index.jpg")
    pic.Load()
    pic.Name = "Obavjestenje"
    pic.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(264, 200)
    pic.TabIndex = 900
    pic.TabStop = False
    pic.Show()


      'filing data into dataset

    dsFilter = New DataSet
    myCommandLoad = New SqlCommand(workerSQL, conn)
    myCommandLoad.CommandTimeout = 200
    adapterLoad.SelectCommand = myCommandLoad
    adapterLoad.Fill(dsFilter)
    adapterLoad.Dispose()
    myCommandLoad.Dispose()
     ' binding dataset and datagrid
    If dsFilter.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then

        pic.Dispose()

        GridControl1.DataSource = dsFilter.Tables(0)

     ' at this point I don't whant to see picturebox while my data is uploaded

    Pic.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: After `pic.show()` add `pic.Refresh()`

Comment: Hm, nothing happens!

Comment: Comment out the line `Pic.Visible = False`. Is the picturebox now visible whan the filing of the dataset is finished?

Comment: Yes I do that and nothing happens I also comment pic.dispose() and it is same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Dim pic As New PictureBox

pic.Width = 222
pic.Height = 173
pic.Location = New Point(?, ?)

pic.ImageLocation = "C:\index.jpg"
pic.Load()

pic.Visible = True

Me.Controls.Add(pic)

pic.Refresh()

'filing data into dataset
...
```

or better

```
Using pic = New PictureBox
    pic.Width = 222
    pic.Height = 173
    pic.Location = New Point(?, ?)

    pic.ImageLocation = "C:\index.jpg"
    pic.Load()

    pic.Visible = True

    Me.Controls.Add(pic)

    pic.Refresh()

    'filing data into dataset
    ...    
    ...
End Using
```

You dont need `pic.Visible = False or dispose` in the end.

valter